# window.open not working on mobile facebook & slack browser

Tags: javascript, forms, facebook, popup, slack

this codes are clearly working on chrome, IE, safari but not working on mobile, facebook and slack, browser.

the device is a iPhone6s.

when I call requestIt() on facebook or slack on iPhone, popup page didn't get form values

javascript

```
function requestIt(){
var formNm = document.frmRegular;

formNm.action = 'url';
var left = (screen.Width - 545) / 2;
var top = (screen.Height - 573) / 2;

var winopts = "left=" + left + ",top=" + top + ",width=545,height=573,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no";
win = window.open("", "billWindow", winopts);
formNm.target = "billWindow";

formNm.submit();
}
```

html

```
 <form id="frmRegular" runat="server"  method="post">
```

Comment: Not every device supports popups. So what?